# how to delete similar values

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

### Problem

I grabed all needed values from array however that contains duplicates. Now I want to remove duplicates. But I can't figure it out on how to do that.

I tried with `$uniq = array_unique($days,SORT_REGULAR)`, but that didn't work at all.

### PHP

```
$days = " ";        
    foreach($data["reports"][1] as $values) {
      $days .= $values['time_pay'];

    }
```

### What returns

```
2016-05-01 00:00:002016-05-01 00:00:002016-05-01 00:00:002016-05-01 00:00:002016-05-01 00:00:002016-05-02 00:00:002016-05-02 00:00:002016-05-02 00:00:002016-05-02 00:00:002016-05-02 00:00:002016-05-02 00:00:002016-05-03 00:00:002016-05-03 00:00:002016-05-03 00:00:002016-05-03 00:00:002016-05-03
```

Comment: Can u share what exactly $data["reports"][1] is supposed to contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `isset` along with `implode` function like as

```
$days = [];        
foreach($data["reports"][1] as $values) {
    if(!in_array($values['time_pay'],$days)){
       $days[] = $values['time_pay'];
    }
}

echo implode($days);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$days = " ";      
$arr =  array();
$i = 0;  
foreach($data["reports"][1] as $values) {
  $arr[$i]= $values['time_pay'];
  $i++;
}
$result = array_unique($arr);
for($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
  $days .= $result[$i];
}
print_r($days);
```

Comment: foreach($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) 
I have question here showed parse error (;) but I couldnt find

Comment: 22 line which I gave below
foreach($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++)

Comment: ohh sorry try with for loop

Comment: $days .= "{$result[$i]}";    try this

Comment: However it returns 2016-05-01 to 2016-05-06 the same result  
2016-05-31 I have information to this date

Comment: i dont know why.. but by using array_unique($arr) you can remove repeated values